# Computing the resultant of two polynomials of degree $4$

Tags: resultant

Let $f=f(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{4}a_ix^i ,g=g(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{4}b_jx^j \in L[x]$, $L$ is a commutative ring. I would like to compute the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f$ and $g$.

I wish to check a few examples in low dimensions, but even in low dimension (with $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$) such as four, the computation is quite lengthy-- the matrix is of order $8$.

I know that there are computer algebra systems that can do these calculations, but unfortunately I have not succeeded to install Macaulay2 on my computer, so I ask for help here; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048049/computing-resultant-of-two-polynomials).

> What is the resultant of $f$ and $g$ as above?

I really apologize if my question is not so appropriate (I would prefer to get help in installing Macaulay2 or a link where one can compute the resultant on-line, but asking for that seems totally not appropriate to this site, and I do not know where to ask these questions).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just curious, what could the exact expression be useful for? You can calculate it online in WA for example [`resultant[ a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4, b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + b_4 x^4 , x ]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+a_0+%2B+a_1+x+%2B+a_2+x%5E2+%2B+a_3+x%5E3+%2B+a_4+x%5E4,+b_0+%2B+b_1+x+%2B+b_2+x%5E2+%2B+b_3+x%5E3+%2B+b_4+x%5E4+,+x+%5D) but it's certainly not pretty (in the general case).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I will try it soon.

Comment: I wish to find a condition on the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ that will imply that the resultant is a nonzero 'scalar'. More precisely, if $L=k[y]$ (so the resultant belongs to $k[y]$), $k$ is a field, I wish that the resultant will belong to $k$.

Comment: Just a thought, but if that's a step towards proving/finding something else, maybe there is another way to get there, more lightweight than resultants.

Comment: Thank you for your advice (and thanks again for the link; it's very helpful!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple, there are $219$ terms:
$$ \eqalign{&{a_{{0}}}^{4}{b_{{4}}}^{4}-{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{1}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}-2
\,{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{2}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}+{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{2}}{b_{{3}
}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-3\,{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{3}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}+3\,{a_
{{0}}}^{3}a_{{3}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{3}}{b_{{
3}}}^{3}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-4\,{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}+4\,{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{4}}b_
{{1}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{4}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}
}^{2}-4\,{a_{{0}}}^{3}a_{{4}}b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+{a_{{0}}}^{3}
a_{{4}}{b_{{3}}}^{4}+{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}+3
\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}
\cr &
-{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+4\,{a_{{0}}}^{
2}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}-{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}b_{{1}
}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}{b_{{
4}}}^{2}+{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-{a_{{0
}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-5\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1
}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}
\cr &
+{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2
}a_{{1}}a_{{4}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}a_{{4}}
b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{3}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}
-2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+{a_{{0}}}^{2
}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{b_{{2}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-5\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{3}
}b_{{0}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}
\cr &
+{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2
}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}
{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{2
}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{
4}}-3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+4\,{a_{{0
}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{3}-2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_
{{2}}a_{{4}}{b_{{2}}}^{3}b_{{4}}+{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}{b_{{2}}}^
{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}-3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^
{2}+3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+3\,{a_{{0
}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{3}
}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
+{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{2}}}^{3}b_{{4}}+5\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{3}}
a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0
}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}
^{3}-5\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+{a_{{0}
}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+3\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{3}
}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}
\cr &
-{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{2}}}^{3}b_{{3}}+6\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{
4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-8\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}
}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-4\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{
2}b_{{4}}+4\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+4\,
{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+2\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}
{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}
\cr &
-4\,{a_{{0}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}+{a_{{0}}}^{2
}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{2}}}^{4}-a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{3}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}-4
\,a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}b_{{0}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}+a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}
a_{{2}}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b
_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4
}}}^{2}
\cr &
-a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{0}}{a_{
{1}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{4}
}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+3\,a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{
2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-3\,a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{
{4}}+a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{3}+3\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}
{a_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}
\cr &
-a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+4\,a_{{0}}a_{{
1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-3\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a
_{{3}}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-3\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}{b_{{
1}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}
}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-8
\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
+3\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}^{3}+a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{
2}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b
_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}{
b_{{3}}}^{2}-5\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}
+a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{0}}a_{
{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-8\,a_{{0}}a_{{
1}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+10\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}a
_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}
b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}-a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b
_{{4}}-2\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+a_{{0
}}a_{{1}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}
\cr &
+5\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{0}}a_
{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}-5\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{4
}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{
b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}-3\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{3}b_{{4}}
+3\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}-a_{{0}}a_{{
1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{3}
\cr &
-2\,a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{3}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{
3}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}
{b_{{4}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4
}}-a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-4\,a_{{0}}{a
_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+4\,a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_
{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-2\,a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}-2\,a_{{0}}{
a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+a_{{0}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{
{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+4\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}
^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}b_{{
4}}-2\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+a_{{0}}a
_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
+2\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-8\,a_{{0}}a
_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+a_{{0}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}
a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0
}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}+3\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{3}b_{
{4}}-a_{{0}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}+2\,a_{{0}
}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-3\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{0}}a_
{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+4\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}
}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}-2\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0
}}{b_{{2}}}^{3}-2\,a_{{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{3}b_{{3}}+a_{
{0}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}{b_{{2}}}^{2}-3\,a_{{0}}{a_{{3}}}
^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
+3\,a_{{0}}{a_{{3}}}^{3}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}-a_{{0}}{a_{{3}}}^{
3}{b_{{1}}}^{3}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{0}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{
2}}b_{{4}}+3\,a_{{0}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}-a_
{{0}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-3\,a_{{0}}{a_{{3}
}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}+a_{{0}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{
b_{{1}}}^{3}b_{{3}}
\cr &
-a_{{0}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{4}}-5\,a_{{0}}a_{{
3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}+a_{{0}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2
}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}+3\,a_{{0}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{
1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}-a_{{0}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{3}b_{{2}}-4\,a_
{{0}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{4}}+4\,a_{{0}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}
}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}
\cr &
+2\,a_{{0}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{2}}}^{2}-4\,a_{{0}}{a_{{4}}}^
{3}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}+a_{{0}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{1}}}^{4}+{a_{{
1}}}^{4}b_{{0}}{b_{{4}}}^{3}-{a_{{1}}}^{3}a_{{2}}b_{{0}}b_{{3}}{b_{{4}
}}^{2}-2\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+{a_{{1}}}^{3
}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-3\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+3\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}a_
{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-{a_{{1}}}^{3}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{3}}}
^{3}+{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}+3\,{a_{{1}}
}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{
{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+4\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}
}}^{2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}
\cr &
-{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-2\,{a_{{1}}}^
{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{4
}}b_{{0}}b_{{2}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+2\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{
2}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-2\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}b_{{
4}}+{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-5\,{a_{{1}}}
^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
+{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+2\,{a_{{1}}}^{
2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}-{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}
}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}b_{{3}}-3\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2
}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+3\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2
}+3\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{4}}-3\,{a_{{1}}
}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}
\cr &
+{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{2}}}^{3}-a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{3}b_{
{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{4}}}^{2}-4\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b
_{{4}}}^{2}+a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+a_
{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}
}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}-a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b
_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{3}}}^{2}
\cr &
+3\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-a_{{1}}a_{{2
}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+4\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_
{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}-3\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0
}}}^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}-3\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{
2}b_{{4}}+a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}-5\,
a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
+a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}+2\,a_{{1}}a_{{2
}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}-a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}
b_{{0}}b_{{1}}{b_{{2}}}^{2}-2\,a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}
}b_{{4}}+a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{3}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{4}}+a_{{1}}{a_{{3
}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{4}}+2\,a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4
}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}
\cr &
-a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{3}}+4\,a_{{1}}a_{{
3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{4}}-a_{{1}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0
}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}-2\,a_{{1}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{
2}}}^{2}+a_{{1}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{2}}-3\,a_{
{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{3}}+3\,a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}
^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}
\cr &
-a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}b_{{0}}{b_{{1}}}^{3}+{a_{{2}}}^{4}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b
_{{4}}}^{2}-{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{3}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{3}}b_{{4}}-2\,{a_{{2}
}}^{3}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}}+{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}
^{2}{b_{{3}}}^{2}+{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{4}
}+3\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{4}}
\cr &
-{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{3}}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{2}}b_{{3}}+2\,{a_{{2}}}^{
2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{4}}-2\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0
}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}+{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{2}}}
^{2}-a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{4}}-4\,a_{{2}}{a_{{3}
}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{4}}+a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}
^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{3}}
\cr &
+3\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{3}}-a_{{2}}a_{{3}}{a_{{
4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}b_{{2}}-2\,a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{
3}b_{{2}}+a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{2}{b_{{1}}}^{2}+{a_{{3}}}^{4}
{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{4}}-{a_{{3}}}^{3}a_{{4}}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{3}}+{a_{{3}}
}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{2}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{2}}
\cr &
-a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}{b_{{0}}}^{3}b_{{1}}+{a_{{4}}}^{4}{b_{{0}}}^{4}
\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I now agree with dxiv that the general case is not nice.. Actually, I wanted to assume that $a_4=b_4=1$;I hope that it is slightly nicer in that case.

Comment: Well, according to WA it is still not so nice if we further assume that $a_4=b_4=1$..

Comment: Arguably, less nice.  Without that assumption, each term is homogeneous of order $4$ in the $a$'s and $4$ in the $b$'s.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I like it (however, I had in mind "nicer" in the sense that the resultant can be expressed by $8$ "unknown" coefficients instead of by $10$ "unknown" coefficients).

Comment: So just erase (i.e. substitute $1$ for) each occurrence of $a_4$ or $b_4$ in the general result.